# Do Global Secondary Indexes suffer from hot key issues

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I know tables in DynamoDB require even distribution between shards to utilize read/write capacity, is this true for Global Secondary Indexes too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, GSIs have the same guidelines as regular table indexes. You should follow the same guidelines described in [Guidelines for Working with Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload). The [Guidelines for Global Secondary Indexes documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForGSI.html) gives an example where a poorly chosen key can lead to hot-spotting and uneven activity accross partitions.:

> For example, suppose you have an Employee table with attributes such
>   as Name, Title, Address, PhoneNumber, Salary, and PayLevel. Now
>   suppose that you had a global secondary index named PayLevelIndex,
>   with PayLevel as the hash key. Many companies only have a very small
>   number of pay codes, often fewer than ten, even for companies with
>   hundreds of thousands of employees. Such an index would not provide
>   much benefit, if any, for an application.
>
> **Another problem with PayLevelIndex is the uneven distribution of
>   distinct values.** For example, there may be only a few top executives
>   in the company, but a very large number of hourly workers. **Queries on
>   PayLevelIndex will not be very efficient because the read activity
>   will not be evenly distributed across partitions.**

Comment: while it may not be efficient, what options do i have while dealing with these usecase?

Comment: @bestwishes Use random sharding. Create a suffix with a random number i.e. MY_KEY#42. When reading you have to read from all possible partitions to get all entries. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html